# Vlookup between 2 Microsoft List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column

I have 2 sharepoint/microsoft list files.
I want to create a reconciliation of two columns( x and y) in 2 separate files/lists(a and b) and spit out the differences into a new file or in a new column in List b.
I thought a vlookup type of function may be able to help with this.
Can anyone help me do this? Please inform me if I am in the wrong exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that there are lists A and B in the SharePoint. You want to a column Z in the list B to store differences between column  X in the list A and column Y in the list B. Is it right?

First, Vlookup column is not supported in the SharePoint. You can only display column X in the list B through lookup column. You cannot calculate differences between two columns.

Create a lookup column in the list B.
[image]